# Parsing polymorphic object with objectmapper

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, strava

I am trying to parse a polymorphic object (it is from the Strava api) with a jackson object mapper. The object looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "latlng",
    "data": [
      [ 38.603734, -122.864112 ],
      [ 38.608798, -122.867714 ],

      ... omitted for brevity ...

      [ 38.611205, -122.870848 ],
      [ 38.603579, -122.863891 ]
    ],
    "series_type": "distance",
    "original_size": 512,
    "resolution": "low"
  },
  {
    "type": "distance",
    "data": [
      0.0,
      1305.8,

      ... omitted for brevity ...

      128136.6,
      129444.1
    ],
    "series_type": "distance",
    "original_size": 512,
    "resolution": "low"
  }
]
```

So based on the type the field data has a different object in it. In most cases it is an array of floats. In the case of the "latlng", there is an array of float[], so it is a float[][] (I would think).
I create an object that represents this data structure, with a deserializer. It looks like this:

```
public class StravaStream {


    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }


    public static class StravaStream1D extends StravaStream {
        @JsonProperty("data")
        private float[] data;

        public StravaStream1D() {
        }

        public float[] getData() {
            return data;
        }


    }

    public static class StravaStream2D extends StravaStream {

        @JsonProperty("data")
        private float[][] data;

        public StravaStream2D() {
        }

        public float[][] getData() {
            return data;
        }

    }

    public StravaStream() {
    }


    public static class StravaStreamDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<StravaStream> {
        public StravaStreamDeserializer() {
            super(StravaStream.class);
        }

        @Override
        public StravaStream deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            Class<? extends StravaStream> variantStravaStream;
            ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
            ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jp);
            JsonNode type = root.get("type");
            System.out.println("type is "+type);
            if (type.textValue().equals("latlng")) {
                variantStravaStream = StravaStream2D.class;
            } else {
                variantStravaStream = StravaStream1D.class;
            }
                System.out.println("variant is "+variantStravaStream.getSimpleName());

            return mapper.readValue(jp, variantStravaStream);
        }
    }
}
```

When I only ask for one dimensional data, like distance objects or so, it works out fine. But when I try to parse the "latlng" float[][], jackson fails. I am sure that the type is recognized, see the additonal system.out, it prints that a StravaStream2D.class variant is used.
The error message (and the additional system out) I get is:

```
01-26 09:05:49.605 27165-27165/nl.jfvh.stravatest I/System.out: type is "latlng"
01-26 09:05:49.605 27165-27165/nl.jfvh.stravatest I/System.out: variant is StravaStream2D
01-26 09:05:49.620 27165-27165/nl.jfvh.stravatest W/System.err: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of float[] out of VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT token
01-26 09:05:49.620 27165-27165/nl.jfvh.stravatest W/System.err:     at [Source: java.io.StringReader@e8550ec; line: 1, column: 40164] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->nl.jfvh.stravatest.client.model.StravaStream2D["data"]->[Ljava.lang.Object[][0])
```

Is my data model wrong? The parsing of polymorphic objects is very new for me, I followed some tutorials, but the problems seems to be in the simple mapping of the data on the float[][]...

Answer (score 0):

Since (according to you) you are new to parsing polymorphic objects, I'd suggest using annotations instead of a custom deserialiser. It's as simple as:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "latlng", value = StravaStream.StravaStream2D.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "distance", value = StravaStream.StravaStream1D.class)
})
public class StravaStream {
```

Read docs for [JsonTypeInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html) and [JsonSubTypes](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSubTypes.html)

An issue with the custom deserialiser you're trying with is that when you do `return mapper.readValue(jp, variantStravaStream);` at the end it will actually re-enter the deserializer because `class StravaStream2D extends StravaStream` so Jackson will use the custom deserializer again. I got stack overflow errors when trying this due to infinite recursion.